# Is it okay to ask a question like this one:

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm pretty new to using *meta* on any of the stackexchange sites.  Do the meta sites have the same rigorous standards about what is okay to ask?  Is it okay to ask questions that are about something like *the nature of the community*? To give a concrete example, would something like

> Is it my imagination, or are the people on Drupal Answers uniformly more friendly than on other SE sites?

be an acceptable question?  If not, why not?

(And yes, I've read the FAQ.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acceptable questions on a meta site are also about the community behind the main site too. When you ask if a question is acceptable, and the FAQ doesn't have already specify that kind of question is not acceptable, you are asking to that community if that type of question is acceptable.

That said, the question you used as example is rather subjective. There isn't an objective way to measure the friendliness of a Stack Exchange community, and the question would probably closed as not constructive.

Comment: "When you ask if a question is acceptable... you are asking *to that community* if that type of question is acceptable."  (Emphasis mine.) So this is why every site seems to have different standards?  It's intended to be that way?

Comment: There are questions that are considered bad questions in all the Stack Exchange sites; for the other questions, it's the community behind a Stack Exchange site that decide which questions are welcome. Sometimes Stack Exchange staff can set some limits, if they see dangerous questions coming out at network level, such as in the case of the "shopping" questions.